# Eclipse discards build path when adding jar

Tags: java, eclipse

**Expected:**
Adding a jar (external or internal) to my build path, it would be added, and otherwise preserve the other libraries in the build path.

**Actual:**

1. right-click on my java project and choose `Build Path`->`Configure Build Path...`
2. choose `Libraries` tab
3. click on `Classpath` item
4. click `Add JARs...`(issue also occurs if I select `Add External JARs...` here)
5. select the JAR I need to add
6. `Modulepath` and `Classpath` items and all of their respective children on the `Libraries` tab are now missing.

**Details:**

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works as expected. What version of Eclipse?

Comment: thanks @greg-449 i've added the details in an edit

Comment: Have you tried it with the current release? Do you have write access to the project's `.classpath` file? Are there any entries in the Error Log view, or if you don't have that view, the workspace's `.metadata/.log` file? Is this happening on all Java projects, or just one?

Comment: Did you install a Java BETA plug-in in the past (maybe you run into [Eclipse bug 526065](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526065))?